# How to make Steam scan existing files when there is no disk space left

Tags: steam

I have a 120 GB SSD that I just installed. I moved Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege over to it so I can have faster loading times in the game. It takes up almost all of the storage space that the drive has. Now when I go into Steam and try the classic "Install" trick to make it see the files, it says I don't have enough disk space.

Also, I already did set the drive as a Steam download library correctly. I also transferred over the appmanifest file and restarted Steam but when it finished validating, it told me that, I don't have enough disk space.

Is there a way around the checking of free space on the disk?

Comment: I'm quite sure you missed a source path telling steam that your game is now located at a new location. I don't have access to steam right now so I can't check it for you but have you checked the steam_api.ini or steam.ini (something like that) file?

Comment: Maybe you need to edit the content of the appmanifest file, not just copy it?  (I don't actually know, just guessing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you downloaded and installed Rainbow Six Siege through Steam, the best way to move your game files is to **let Steam itself move the game**:

[image]

- <kbd>Right-click</kbd> the game in your library
- go to '*Properties*'
- go to the '*Local Files*' tab
- Here you find the option to '*Move Install Folder...*'.

In your case, I suggest moving the files back to their original folder, and take that route.

Comment: I wasn't even aware Steam had this function. I can't believe I haven't seen this suggested in other places. I'll give this a shot and report back.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work as the drive I took Siege from was almost full as well and demanding what is basically 218 GB of storage space to put it back and check it. It seems like Steam isn't checking to see if the files are there for some reason which is weird because it scanned for game files in the past. I've already committed to uninstalling and reinstalling the game but maybe this answer can help others with the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: What is the "classic install trick" you refer to in your original post, is it manually moving the files to a folder and then let Steam 'install' it there again? If that is the case, then that might be your answer: Steam will first look for free space to install the files it thinks it needs to download, before starting the scanning process to see what content it actually has.

Comment: I have added an additional stand-alone solution, which might work better in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If, as in the OP's case, the installation folder has already been moved manually, and Steam would need too much additional space before being able to scan the installation folder and 're-install', **I suggest using [Steam Mover](http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover)**.

This program lets Steam think the game files are in one place, while they are actually in another.

! Note that my other answer (letting Steam handle the migration process) is the preferred solution, but this can be used as a last resort.

<sup>This is posted as an additional answer, since it is better suited for the OP's situation, and offers an independent and completely different solution.</sup>